# HTML Minification in C#

Tags: c#, html, minify

Tried searching around for a complete library for HTML Minification in C# but haven't been able to locate anything that is useful ?

Does anyone here have such a library or know of one ?

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate of your suggested question. He is asking for a C# library that can minify HTML code and not an online tool.

Comment: yeah exactly - i dont want a "copy | paste" web solution - i need a C# library to do this on the fly

Comment: I use http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/

Comment: Fair enough. I was just posting it as a possible.

Comment: I can't find it now but I have seen an HTTP Module for ASP.net that does it at runtime.  Do you need it for C# code independent of the ASP.net framework?

Comment: I've just [ported the core parts](http://blog.magerquark.de/c-port-of-googles-htmlcompressor-library/) of Google's **htmlcompressor** library to C#, if anyone is interested.

Comment: http://madskristensen.net/post/efficient-stylesheet-minification-in-c

Answer (score 5):

As for static HTML compression, I found this port of [Google’s htmlcompressor library](http://blog.magerquark.de/c-port-of-googles-htmlcompressor-library/). I wrapped it in MSBuild Task and I'm happy:)

Comment: Thanks for using my library :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try my extension for static minification: [MinifyOnSave](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/71e99177-37b6-40d8-8669-4d61f804f0c5)

The source code is also available on [GitHub](https://github.com/desmati/MinifyOnSave).